# how to add helper in rails admin dashboard actions in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I`m using Rails Admin gem https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin and I am upgrading to the latest version of it.

In the old version of rails admin (0.6.5) and rails (4.1.0) the helper class is loaded and all work fine. After upgrade to rails 5 and rails admin to master branch the helpers does not work anymore. I call operator_name in view and this return 
`NoMethodError - undefined method 'operator_name' for #<<Class:0x007febe6d22510>:0x007febd334fb90>`

I searched in the rails admin wiki but did not find, someone have idea why this occurs?

Dashboard action class and helper module above:

## Dashboard Action Class

```
# my_project/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/callcenter_stats.rb

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class CallcenterStats < Dashboard

        register_instance_option :authorization_key do
          :callcenter_stats
        end

        register_instance_option :route_fragment do
          'callcenter_stats'
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get,:post]
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-calendar'
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          Proc.new do
            # code ...
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## helper

```
# my_project/app/helper/rails_admin/callcenter_stats_helper.rb

module RailsAdmin
  module CallcenterStatsHelper

    def operator_name email
      email[/(.*?)@.*/,1].split('.').map(&:capitalize).join("<br/>").html_safe
    end

  end
end
```

Thanks for attention.

Comment: I am currently having the same problem even though I still have rails 4 app. I tried to upgrade to `rails_admin 1.1.0` and cannot access my helpers in `app/helpers`. Did you figure that out? Thx

Comment: @Bachet You have to include ApplicationHelper in rails_admin.rb file.

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  include ApplicationHelper
end

Comment: I passed the task on to someone else, but I believe @ArturTrzop answer is correct. Tks guys

Answer (score 2):

**Try that**

It seems like this is the most important part ;)

> changing the `config.parent_controller` as described [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed)

**If it still doesn't work**

Here is what I did.

After some good time trying between updating `rails_admin`, downgrading it, reinstalling it, typing `bin/spring stop`, changing the `config.parent_controller` as described [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed) then I decided to modify one of my custom actions where I needed a helper (I added `helper TableHelper` in the custom action).

And I can't explain why, it didn't work on the page I wanted but worked on another action where the exact same helper is called...

Another error appeared with Kaminari views not being found. So I had to move pagination partials from `app/views/kaminari` to `app/views/kaminari/`

Another server restart and it was working everywhere... So I removed the code added in the custom action.

Not very clear explanation but maybe it can help someone else! :)

Answer (score 1):

OMG! After one year i find the solution.
The problem is new way to load helpers on Rails 5.
Read In [RubyOnRails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html)

> In previous versions of Rails the controller will include a helper which matches the name of the controller, e.g., MyController will automatically include MyHelper. To return old behavior set config.action_controller.include_all_helpers to false.

I create `my_app/app/helpers/rails_admin/custom_helper.rb` with

```
module RailsAdmin::CustomHelper
  include RailsAdmin::CallcenterStatsHelper
  include RailsAdmin::CustomerContactsHelper
  include RailsAdmin::DiscountCouponHelper
  include RailsAdmin::SharedUrlsHelper
  include RailsAdmin::FormHelper
end
```

and include on `my_app/config/initializers/rails_admin_main_controller.rb`

```
module RailsAdmin::MainController.class_eval do
  include RailsAdmin::CustomHelper
end
```

and works fine ;D
This is not a Rails Admin issue, is only and update from rails

Comment: This is not working for me. `gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.2'`